# Can I modify the default CSS styles used in Jupyter Lab markdown tags?

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I like to use markdown in Jupyter Lab (currently v2.2.6 from Anaconda) to create documentation for many of my projects. I would like to modify the default styles that are rendered in markdown cells.  I know I can use  tags to do this inline but that gets pretty tedious.  I'm assuming there's a set of CSS files somewhere that define the default styles for markdown in my notebooks.

As an example, when I use "#" to indicate h1, the default text color is black.  Is there a CSS file somewhere that I could edit to change the default color to red so that whenever I create a notebook and use "#" in a markdown cell, the heading style would always be red?

TIA for any help.

Comment: Do you want the changes to be visible only for you or for everyone who opens your notebooks? For the first one you could create your own JupyterLab theme (which is pretty straightforward), for the other you would likely need to embed CSS as a style in each notebook.

Comment: @krassowski - I think I would need to provide for both scenarios so I'm thinking embedding CSS in each notebook is probably what I'm looking for.  Do you know what the process for that would look like?  E.g., reference a style sheet that contains the desired style for h1 and then add that reference to any notebook I wanted to share or would I need to copy/paste the actual CSS 'inline' in a markdown cell for every notebook?  If you know of a resource I could look at it'd be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there is a generic solution for JupyterLab. If you are willing to use a code cell for that (and are storing code outputs in notebooks) you could make a code cell that reads a file and displays it as an HTML output.